# Flutter exception after adding the Padding widget

Tags: flutter

I have the following `Table` inside `Card`. Since I added the padding widget, I get the following error:

```
    I/flutter (19671): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (19671): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (19671): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/table.dart': Failed assertion: line 882 pos 16: 'tableWidth >=
I/flutter (19671): targetWidth': is not true.
I/flutter (19671): 
I/flutter (19671): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (19671): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (19671): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (19671):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (19671): 
I/flutter (19671): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (19671): #2      RenderTable._computeColumnWidths (package:flutter/src/rendering/table.dart:882:16)
I/flutter (19671): #3      RenderTable.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/table.dart:1000:33)
```

code:

```
body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0), margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Card(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Table(
                          children: list)
                    ])
            )
      )
```

1. Why adding the padding widget throws this error?
2. How I can add padding and margin for my Card?

Comment: whats the full stacktrace (or at least top 5-6 frames)?

Comment: @pskink Added it now.

Comment: This worked fine - `body: Container(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Card(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                      Table(children: [
                        TableRow(children: [Text('1'), Text('1'), Text('1')]),
                        TableRow(children: [Text('1'), Text('1'), Text('1')]),
                      ])
                    ]))))`

Answer (score 0):

1. Because of 2 it won't account for growth in the container based on the padding, it will pad inward causing the inners to overflow. Just use the provided properties from Container.
2. Container has a padding and margin property which can be applied. You don't nee to wrap your Containers child with padding.

   Container(
     child: Text(),
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
     margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)
   )

See [Container-class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) for more properties that can be used

Comment: Adding the padding on the Container widget (and removing the Padding widget) sill throws the exception.

Comment: @TheUnreal then given this statement in the message. 'tableWidth >=
I/flutter (19671): targetWidth': is not true. I would say it's your list item and not the container with the padding.